# saber si existe un archivo para no sobre escribirlo

Tags: javascript, nodejs

debo utilizar esta funcion ?

> fs.exists(path, callback)

no se como hacer la funcion para saber si ya existe el archivo con el mismo nombre, y si no entonces crearlo

mi funcion es:

```
function escribir(archivo,data){
fs.stat('./archivos/'+archivo+'.txt', function(err, stat) {
if(err == null) {
    console.log('File exists');
} else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {

    fs.writeFile('./archivos/'+archivo+'.txt', data, function(err) {
    if( err ){
        console.log( err );
    }
    else{
        console.log('Se ha escrito correctamente');
    }
    });
} else {
    console.log('Some other error: ', err.code);
}
```

});
}

Comment: Hola, no debes usar esa función pues esta obsoleta. Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de que/como lo intentas hacer? para tener mas contexto y poder darte una respuesta completa. Salu2

Comment: @rnd lo modifique, puse mi funcion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes algunas opciones, veamos algunas.

#### Síncrono

Si prefieres la manera síncrona, hay un par de métodos en la API que puedes usar.

**fs#accessSync**

Este método comprueba si un archivo es accesible. Si no lo es, es decir, si no existe, lanzará una excepción.

```
try {
  if(fs.accessSync('/archivo.dat')) {
    // existe
  }
} catch (e) {
  // no existe
}
```

Puedes crear una wrapper para esto:

```
function fileExists(path) {
  try {
    if(fs.accessSync('/archivo.dat')) {
      return true;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**fs#statSync**

La solución anterior es válida, pero, ¿qué pasaría si hay un directorio y un archivo con el mismo nombre? Lo que pasaría es que no lanzaría ninguna excepción y si olvidamos esto, nos puede causar un dolor de cabeza al depurar.

La solución más viable sería **statSync**. Esta función te permite saber si e archivo encontrado es un directorio o un archivo.

```
function fileExists(path) {
  try {
    return fs.statSync(path).isFile();
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

> Ten en cuenta que pueden haber errores al tratar de ver la disponibilidad de un archivo/directorio; en este caso sería mejor devolver false solo si el código de error es `ENOENT` (error no entry): `if(e.code === 'ENOENT')` y relanzar el error o manejarlo si ocurrió otro error, como por ejemplo por `permisos`.

Si lo quisiésemos adaptar para saber si es un directorio solo tendremos que cambiar `isFile` por `isDirectory`.

#### Asíncrono

El modo asíncrono de las funciones es muy parecido, la diferencia es que reciben un callback.

```
function fileExists(file, cb) {
  fs.stat(file, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
        return cb(null, false);
      } else { // en caso de otro error
        return cb(err);
      }
    }
    // devolvemos el resultado de `isFile`.
    return cb(null, stats.isFile());
  });
}
```

Y se usaría de la siguiente manera:

```
fileExists('/archivo.dat', (err, exists) => {
  if(err) {
    // manejar otro tipo de error
  }
  if(exists) {
    // hacer algo si existe
  } else {
    // hacer algo si no existe
  }
});
```

O si prefieres las promesas, puedes usar el módulo [es6-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise):

```
function existsFile(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.stat(file, (err, stats) => {
        if (err) {
          if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
           resolve(false);
          } else { // en caso de otro error
            reject(err);
          }
        }
        // devolvemos el resultado de `isFile`.
        resolve(stats.isFile());
      });
  });
}
```

Lo usaríamos de la siguiente manera:

```
existsFile('/archivo.dat')
  .then(exists => {
    if(exists) {

    } else {

    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // manejar error
  });
```

Comment: lo resolvi asi `function escribir(archivo,data){
 fs.stat('./archivos/'+archivo+'.txt', function(err) {  
    if (err) {
     
fs.writeFile('./archivos/'+archivo+'.txt', data, function(err) {});
    
       
    } else {
        // file exists
    }
});
 
}`

Comment: en el primer ejemplo la variable fs que significa?

Comment: @DavidRamírezC. fs hace referencia al módulo de sistema de archivos de Node.js: `const fs = require('fs')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(fs.existsSync("./archivo")){
        console.log("El archivo EXISTE!");
  }else{
        console.log("El archivo NO EXISTE!");
  }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que puedas mejorar la respuesta y el usuario pueda entenderte mejor.

Comment: fs que significa?